# Cannot convert array to Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript

In native script app with typescript I'm attempting to pass android.net.Uri array to a function.
Then I receive the mentioned error. I read about creating Array with Array.create("classTtype", count), but can't use it (Property 'create' does not exist on type 'ArrayConstructor') - using es5. 
Here how I create the array actually, but it's not working:
 let result: android.net.Uri[] = new Array(1);
 result[0] = android.net.Uri.parse(dataString);

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're close but a problem may arise if you are not using a newer version of {N} since the typings (assuming you are using typescript) was added a couple versions ago (can't remember which) you can try the following assuming it's typescript

```js
// ts
const result = (Array as any).create('android.net.Uri', count);
result[0] = android.net.Uri.parse(dataString);
```

```js
// js
const result = Array.create('android.net.Uri', count);
result[0] = android.net.Uri.parse(dataString);
```

[Core e.g](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/e4211294580e20ca83668bd7ee584a77a25fae28/nativescript-core/ui/styling/background.android.ts#L119-L120)